# Injecting RecyclerView.Adapter using Dagger

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-recyclerview, dagger-2, android-mvp

I'm trying to inject a `RecyclerView` adapter into an `Activity`, but i'm not getting the result I'm expecting. The list is not being filled.

> This is my adapter implementation:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListItemViewHolder> {

private TopMoviesActivityMVP.Presenter presenter;

public ListAdapter(TopMoviesActivityMVP.Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListAdapter.ListItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_movie_list, parent, false);
    return new ListItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListAdapter.ListItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    presenter.bindRowViewAtPosition(holder, position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return presenter.getRowsCount();
}

public static class ListItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements TopMoviesRowView {

    @BindView(R.id.tv_task_name)
    TextView tvName;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_task_country)
    TextView tvCountry;

    public ListItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        tvName.setText(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        tvCountry.setText(country);
    }

}}
```

As you can see the adapter receives an instance of the `presenter`, which is being used to get access to the downloaded data. Inside my `activity` I'm trying to inject the `adapter`:

```
public class TopMoviesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TopMoviesActivityMVP.View {

@BindView(R.id.list_activity_rootview)
ViewGroup rootView;
@BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Inject
TopMoviesActivityMVP.Presenter presenter;
@Inject
RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListItemViewHolder> listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_movies);

    ((App)getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    presenter.setView(this);
    presenter.loadData();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    presenter.rxUnsubscribe();
}

@Override
public void updateData() {
    int count = presenter.getRowsCount();
    if (count == 0) {
        listAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
    } else {
        listAdapter.notifyItemInserted(count-1);
    }
}

@Override
public void showSnackbar(String msg) {
    Snackbar.make(rootView, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Even when `listAdapter.notifyItemInserted` is being called after the downloaded data is available, `onCreateViewHolder` is not being called.

If I don't inject the adapter, everything works as expected:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(presenter);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

> This is my module:

```
@Module
public class TopMoviesModule {

@Provides
public RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListItemViewHolder> providesAdapter(TopMoviesActivityMVP.Presenter presenter) {
    return new ListAdapter(presenter);
}

@Provides
public TopMoviesActivityMVP.Presenter providesTopMoviesPresenter(TopMoviesActivityMVP.Model model) {
    return new TopMoviesPresenter(model);
}

@Provides
public TopMoviesActivityMVP.Model providesTopMoviesModel(Repository repository) {
    return new TopMoviesModel(repository);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public Repository providesRepository(MoviesApiService moviesApiService, CountryApiService countryApiService) {
    return new TopMoviesRepository(moviesApiService, countryApiService);
}}
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its because of the scoping, the thing is that since presenter doesn't have a scope attached to it you're getting 2 different instances of the presenter in the Activity and the adapter. You can confirm that by adding a break-point to your code.

Also it would be very wrong to have a singleton scoped presenter that gets tied up with the Application scope.

I would recommend using a subcomponent for your Activity with a custom scope so it doesn't outlive the activity and you can have the adapter and presenter scoped to that Activity.

For more info on Dagger Subcomponents check this [link](https://google.github.io/dagger/android)

Comment: You're totally right. I am getting two different instances of the presenter. Adding the @Singleton annotation to the presenter provider fixes it, but I will give a read to the Subcomponents topic. thanks